# Are max_connections per page or per query?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

My small company has built and hosted over 300 sites. Only a select few,
literally 2 or 3 have failed to load due to the max_connections setting being too low. My question is, are max_connections based on per page or per query?

We use a lot of Ajax to load elements and improve the user experience. Our
user dashboard may send 5 Ajax calls per page and each call queries
the MySql database separately. Are those considered 5 concurrent connections
or 1?

Comment: based on per total. [Manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: run `show processlist;` continuously, while one browser user bangs away at the app.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll have to figure out what it means but I loaded the dashboard and ran that and get rows like:

( id, command, sleep )
( 646696, sleep, 4 )

Comment: Each row is a connection

Comment: Question answered then, if you post it as the answer I'll accept it. Its a good thing internet speeds are what they are and pages are served quick but an eye opener for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection count from the perspective of the server is visible to you too by running

```
show processlist;
```

Each row in that output represents a connection. Keep in mind there may be overhead developer connections not representative of app users. The server is oblivious to whether you are coming in from PHP, java, you name it. It is a resource, and it dwindles. Which is another reason for RESTful services, constantly opening and closing connections. Care should be taken to close connections in apps as soon as possible.

We have all seen a lot of code, especially Java, way more than PHP, that does not have a connection Garbage Collected (GC) yet. There is still a reference count on the object that was not closed properly, and these errors occur that you are experiencing.

A [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) to get started looking at other links. Here is one for [Show Processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html).